# subtract two Dates in Linq to Entities which returns a timespan

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to subtract two Dates and get the value in Timespan for Example

`TimeSpan duration = Convert.ToDateTime(completeDate).Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(lastRundate));`

This is for Normal implementation. HOw can one do it in Linq to Entities in Entity Framework wherein

```
from job in Jobs
   select new JobEntity
  {                                                  
  Duration =  job.CompleteDate.Value.Subtract(job.NextRunDate.Value)
  };
```

where Jobs is my table, CompleteDate & NextRunDate are my column names of DataType DateTime? (since it allows null value)
When I tried this code, it gives me this error

*LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan Subtract(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.*
Please do let me know how to go about this. 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Why not extend your `JobEntity` model?

```
public DateTime NextRunDate { get; set; }
public DateTime CompletedDate { get; set; }
public Timespan Duration
{
    get
    {
        return CompleteDate.Subtract(NextRunDate)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [EntityFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395607.aspx):

```
from job in Jobs
select new JobEntity
{                                                  
    Duration = EntityFunctions.DiffSeconds(job.CompleteDate, job.NextRunDate)
};
```

You need `using System.Data.Objects;` in your code file for this. It will return the time span in seconds as an `int`.

Comment: EntityFunctions is deprecated. Use DbFunctions.DiffHours() instead.